# Ext4 and Linux - very large number of files in one directory - operations

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, scripting, ext4

I have a problem with a very large number of files in one directory.

The file system is ext4.

I reached the 2**32 file limit and couldn't even write any file on this partition.

The problem is very big.

I don't know how I can move some of the files to other resources?

The classic "ls" and "mv" are not working.
The files is too much...

Is there any way to quickly output any file in bash?

One arbitrary file per directory, which is almost 2**32 files.

If I can download one file quickly, I can write a script.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear whether you know file names or not. Also, it's not clear what you really want.

You want a file listing? You want to inspect individual files?

Comment: It's difficult to identify files names patterns. It's fair to assume that there is no known file name pattern. Is it possible to get the names of, for example, one or ten or a hundred files in this directory quickly?

Comment: Does `ls --sort=none --no-group` work for you? It will take some time to run but it will be finite.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Good reply, but you can also head the output and get a list of maybe 100 files. Because of the non-sort, these will also be physically at the start of the directory, so quick to mv them too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try running:

```bsh
ls --sort=none --no-group
```

or limit to some number of files, e.g.

```bsh
ls --sort=none --no-group | head -500
```

Comment: The original poster is unresponsive, so maybe we'd better wait for his reply before you deem my answer unsatisfactory. He's had troubles running `ls` and `mv` without arguments.

Comment: @Isaac Of course, this is an answer to the question. I might have given the same.

Comment: It's about the only possible answer for a huge directory. `ls` with any kind of sorting (the default) has to read it all before the first output comes. The only possible alternative is `find` (but I never tried that). Or C using readdir() if you need the exercise.

Comment: Artem, or @HaukeLaging or anyone else: any idea if this is some sort of GNU thing or will all `ls` implementations work this way? This `--sort=none` trick is really useful! (update: I guess it must be GNU, I don't see this option in https://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/1posix/ls/)

Comment: @terdon interestingly the [other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/599925/100397) says that even with this `--sort=none` option `ls` will still read in all the files

Comment: @roaima I'm not sure. I have created a directory with a ridiculous number of files (18544022). Running `command ls` does eventually work, although it takes a few _minutes_ to start printing. Conversely,  `command ls  --sort=none --no-group` happily lists out the files after a few seconds. So the options certainly help. I haven't managed to reproduce a case where `command ls` alone fails completely though. (using `command` to ensure no aliases with any other options are involved).

Comment: @roaima `ls -l` tries to align the output of columns in accordance with the maximum digits in any size entry. If it is only listing short 1-column name output without sorting, it can (and should) report as it reads. --sort may be GNU style, but -U is Linux and Unix (I used on at least Solaris and AIX).

Answer (score 2):

Using `ls` to operate on a large directory is very inefficient, since GNU `ls` will read *all* of the entries in the directory before returning *any* of them, even with `--sort=none`, because it wants the output to be "pretty".  This is both slow and uses a lot of RAM, since an ext4 directory can have many millions of files in it.

Instead, you should use `find` to list files in the directory, which will print out the filenames as soon as they are read from the directory.  If you want to find particular files (e.g. all the "*.jpg" files smaller than 1MB), you could run e.g.

```
find /my/directory -type f -name "*.jpg" -size -1M
```

See the [find(1) man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) for full details on how to use it.

Once you find a bunch of of files you want to do something with, then you can use `xargs` to run a command for each file.  For example, to delete temporary files use e.g.:

```
find /my/directory -name "*.tmp" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

or to move them into a different directory like:

```
find /my/directory -name "*.jpg" -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' mv '{}' /my/otherdirectory
```

or any number of things.  The `xargs` program runs the specific command for each file that it reads from the standard input, see [xargs(1) man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) for details.  The `mv` command is a bit more complex than `rm` because `mv` needs to put the target directory at the end of the command, while `xargs` normally adds all the files after the specified command.

You could instead save the list of files to an output file like `find ... > /tmp/file_list` and then edit `file_list` to contain only the files you want to delete/move, and pipe it into `xargs` separately:

```
xargs -a /tmp/file_list -I '{}' mv '{}' /my/otherdir
```